# Lodash/underscore: Convert array of objects to single object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have an array of objects that looks like so:

```
var A = [{key:"key1",val:1},{key:"key2",val:2},...,{key:"keyn",val:n}]
```

And I want to transform `A` to an object:

```
{
    key1: 1,
    key2: 2,
    ...
    keyn: n
}
```

This usecase has never come up, but I was thinking of doing `mapKeys` and then `mapValues` and I feel there's a simpler answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a built-in way that I can’t find, but:

```
var result = _.zipObject(
    _.pluck(A, 'key'),
    _.pluck(A, 'val')
);
```

Answer (score 9):

You don't really need lodash to achieve that. Just do this with [array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). See code sample below:

```
function transformArray(arraySrc){
    return arraySrc.reduce(function(prev, curr){
        prev[curr.key] = curr.val;
        return prev;
    }, {});
}

transformArray([{key:"key1",val:1},{key:"key2",val:2},{key:"key3",val:3}]);
```

Comment: I'm upvoting your answer because i like using native `Array.prototype.reduce` but @minitech answered using lodash so i'm accepting his/hers

Comment: understood. Thanks for taking the time to explain

Comment: Probably should return *newObject*, or just `return arraySrc.reduce(...);`. ;-)

Comment: @RobG you're correct. I'll be updating the function to return the computed value...

Comment: @ShaharZ: You could replace `Array.prototype.reduce` with [`_.reduce`](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce) if you need an Underscore/lodash approach.

Answer (score 4):

I'd do this:

```
var result = _(A).keyBy('key').mapValues('val').value();
```

Clear and simple.

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to use _.extend.

```
let list = [{"foo":"bar"},{"baz":"faz"},{"label":"Hello, World!"}];
let singleObject = _.extend.apply({}, list);
```

Output:

```
{foo: "bar", baz: "faz", label: "Hello, World!"}
```

Answer (score 3):

Updating @ry answer to a newer version of lodash:

```
var result = _.zipObject(
    _.map(A, 'key'),
    _.map(A, 'val')
);
```